# How to identify duplicated values over multiple unsorted columns?

Tags: python, pandas

Sorry for the title but to explain my problem, I made a small dataframe that look like my real dataset :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'user': ['u1', 'u2', 'u3', 'u4', 'u5'],
 'date': ['1. August 2023',
  '5. January 2023',
  '2. May 2023',
  '13. July 2023',
  '1. January 2023'],
 'task1': ['A', 'D', 'G', 'B', 'J'],
 'task2': ['B', 'E', 'H', 'D', 'K'],
 'task3': ['C', 'F', 'A', 'I', 'L']})
print(df)


  user             date task1 task2 task3
0   u1   1. August 2023     A     B     C
1   u2  5. January 2023     D     E     F
2   u3      2. May 2023     G     H     A
3   u4    13. July 2023     B     D     I
4   u5  1. January 2023     J     K     L
```

I need to identify the users that got assigned with tasks that already belongs to others.

I started making a first step with the code below but it gives me empty dataframe.

```
new_df = df.copy()

new_df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(new_df["date"], format="%d. %B %Y")

new_df = new_df.sort_values("date")

new_df = new_df.loc[new_df[['task1', 'task2', 'task3']].duplicated()]
```

My expected output is this : `tasks_to_reassign = {'u4': ['task2'], 'u1': ['task1', 'task2']}`.

Because the task2 (D) assigned to u4 in 13. July 2023 was already assigned to u2 in 5. January 2023. And for u1, task1 (A) and task2 (B) was assigned to him in 1. August 2023 while they were assigned before to u3 in 2. May 2023 and to u4 in 13. July 2023.

Do you guys know how to solve my problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reshape by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) before get duplicates, last aggregate `list` and convert to dictionary:

```
new_df = df.copy()

new_df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(new_df["date"], format="%d. %B %Y")

new_df = new_df.sort_values("date")

new_df = new_df.set_index(['user','date']).stack().reset_index(name='value')

d = new_df[new_df['value'].duplicated()].groupby('user')['level_2'].agg(list).to_dict()
print(d)
{'u1': ['task1', 'task2'], 'u4': ['task2']}
```